# inline/inline-block not working. Divs still stacked

Tags: html, inline, css

I have posted some of this code before, trying to get the sidebar links in the right places and look a special way, I have decided to go in a different direction with that. What I need now is know what I am supposed to do to get the div that I have labeled "content" next to the sidebar instead of below it. I've tried everything. The sidebar and the content div are in the same div together and I've tried displaying in inline, inline-block. Nothing works. I just want them next to each other and level. Can you help me out again? Thanks so much!

**Code displayed here:** http://jsfiddle.net/eNUpJ/11/

**HTML**

```
 </div>
    <div id="wholething">
        <div id="sidebar">
                <h3>Navigation Links</h3>

            <div id="sidelinks">
                <div id="buttons"><a href="#">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div id="buttons"><a href="#">Biography</a>
                </div>
                <div id="buttons"><a href="#">News</a>
                </div>
                <div id="buttons"><a href="#">Music</a>
                </div>
                <div id="buttons"><a href="#">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <p>News stuff and things</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    background: #464646;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
h3 {
    font-family:'Coda', cursive;
    color: white;
    background: #6B6B6B;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0 8px 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
}
#sidelinks {
    font-family:'Armata', sans-serif;
    width: 250;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
#buttons a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #464646;
}
#wholething {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give both #content and #sidebar `float: left`.  You should also remove `display:inline` from #wholething.  Also, you should know that if you want to add anything below the #content and #sidebar - for instance, a footer, with a copyright statement or such - you'll need to give it `clear:both`, which will force it to be below the two floated divs.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give that a try. I've tried using float: right; on the content div and it just made it go right but not up next to the sidebar.

Comment: It worked! I really appreciate it. I'll use that footer thing too. I don't plan on putting any copyright stuff at the bottom though because this is just a practice page. I'm still learning.